# Assigning a Value to an Input Field In a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Solved]: After help determining that my logic was correct, I looked elsewhere for the issue.  I am dynamically creating this table based on other values.  The issue I ran into was that I was setting the input values before the table was being created.  I adjusted the code to execute after the table is created and it is working now.
Thanks for help and tips.

I am attempting to assign a value to the input in each row so that a value can be displayed in the input box.

I attempted doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < (data["rowMax"]+1); i++) {
    $("#vwTearingRowInput"+i).val(data["tearingDelayRow"+i]);
}
```

This would allow me to assign a different value to each input based on a dictionary I have.  This did no work and I believe it is due to me not being able to access the input itself.

My table is setup as so:

```
<table id="vwTable">

<tr id="row 0">
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="0" data-col="0" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="0" data-col="1" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="0" data-col="2" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>

    Tearing Delay: 

    <input id="vwTearingRowInput0" type="number" style="width: 75px;" step="1" value="0" min="0"></input>
</tr>
<tr id="row 1">
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="1" data-col="0" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="1" data-col="2" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>

    Tearing Delay: 

    <input id="vwTearingRowInput1" type="number" style="width: 75px;" step="1" value="0" min="0"></input>
</tr>
<tr id="row 2">
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="2" data-col="0" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="2" data-col="1" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable" data-row="2" data-col="2" style="width: 50px; height: 30px;"></td>

    Tearing Delay: 

    <input id="vwTearingRowInput2" type="number" style="width: 75px;" step="1" value="0" min="0"></input>
</tr>
```

How would you properly access the input field to assign a value to it?

Comment: What is `data` and what is the value of `data["rowMax"]`?

Comment: Your logic seems fine, console.log the variables you are using to make sure they are coming in correctly

Comment: @ekad data is a dictionary of values.  So `data["rowMAX"] = 2 in this case.  It is just the number of rows in the table.

Comment: @ajmajmajma I have tried `console.log(data["tearingDelayRow"+i])` and it provides the expected values.  I also use basically the same format here to bring in the data from the input.  Could there be an issue with `value="0"` in the table that it is setting it back to 0 somehow?

Comment: What's the value of `data["tearingDelayRow"+i]`? Is it numbers?

Comment: Made a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lttbjwrx/) with your html and js. If your `data` is OK, it should work fine.

Comment: @MIvanIsten Hmm very odd, I have `console.log` my data and it is there as expected.  This is now getting even more odd to me, maybe my error is elsewhere.  I just looked, I beleive I am dynamically creating the table after I set the values.  So therefore they are getting set to something that doesn't exists?  I will rework and post an update.  Thank you for showing that my logic was at least correct.

Comment: @ekad  a number but I believe I found the issue, Check comment above ^